# Ubuntu desktop version 16.04 install: server version is the only available choice

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu desktop version 16.04 using a USB stick. I have downloaded a program (the one recommended on the Ubuntu website) that turns the USB stick in to a bootable USB stick. I then boot from that and this comes up:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3

Install Ubuntu Server
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Install MAAS Region Controller
Install MAAS Rack Controller
Check Disc for defects
Rescue a broken system
```

I have installed Ubuntu on another machine and the only option that came up was:

```
Install Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like you downloaded a copy of Ubuntu server, not the desktop version.  [Here is the link to the correct download.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: Thank you I thought i downloaded the desktop version and after i read your post i went back and looked at it and it was the server version, everything is working correctly now.

Comment: @SHRIMPPEOPLE if this post answers your question, don't forget to click the tick mark next to it to mark it as "accepted".